# Nginx URL redirection with WordPress Virtual directory configuration

Tags: wordpress, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm very new to this WordPress/Nginx/Rewrites things and trying get my head round it. So asking the question straight: What's the difference between these two rewrites?

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
    rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-/]+(/wp-admin.*) $1 last;
    rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-/]+(/wp-include.*) $1 last;
    rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-/]+(/.*\.php)$ $1 last;
}
```

and

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
    rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/wp-.*) $1 last;
    rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/.*\.php)$ $1 last;
}
```

The former doesn't work for the sites with `virtual directory` setup but the latter does. How do they different? Something to do with WordPress virtual-directory itself? Sorry if this has been asked before but I cannot figure out anything.

Best,
San

Answer (score 0):

After sifting through the files and directories beginning with `wp-`, the `/wp-content` directory is the only difference on my WordPress installation.

So the answer is probably that:

```
 rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-/]+(/wp-content.*) $1 last;
```

is missing from the first set of rules.